# ALSA: How can I send audio through both headphone and speaker

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio, alsa

I need to control the audio output device at run time :

```
1) Main Speaker only
2) Headphone Only
3) Headphone + Main Speaker both together
```

My application take run time decision to switch among above combinations. What ALSA API should I use for above purpose.

(I use Linux 3.0, ALSA, C, TI tlv320aic3x , ARM).

Comment: uploading your full code will be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this:

```
int snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume(snd_mixer_elem_t *elem,
snd_mixer_selem_channel_id_t channel, long value)
```

[which sets value of playback volume control of a mixer simple element.](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___simple_mixer.html#ga1e4556740beefc8bed40677a316e60ac)

here is a [source code example](http://herrie.info/doxygen/audio__output__alsa_8c_source.html):

```
        /* Set new volume */
         if (snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume(elem,
             SND_MIXER_SCHN_FRONT_LEFT, left_volume) != 0)
                 return (-1);
         if (snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume(elem,
             SND_MIXER_SCHN_FRONT_RIGHT, right_volume) != 0)
                 return (-1);
```